# Importing text file in r

Tags: r, dataframe, import, data-import

I have 26MB of text file with 21 variables and I tried to import the data as:

```
file<-read.table("file.txt", header=FALSE, sep="\t",skip=10)
```

For some reason, it is loaded a data with one variable. Any suggestion is appreciated?

My sessionInfo looks like:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Edit:
Here is some of the data:

```
8760
201001010100
201001010100
00001    -9.0
00002   18
    201001010100      00002     0.0000        100.0000        250.0000        500.0000        750.0000       1000.0000       1500.0000       2000.0000       3000.0000       4000.0000       5000.0000       6000.0000       7500.0000       8500.0000      10000.0000      12000.0000      15000.0000      18000.0000
    201001010100      00002     86.8757         89.1179         90.9795         97.8640         99.0000         99.0000         99.0000         99.0000         99.0000         98.5143         86.4022         83.7819         63.1753         63.1753         15.9124         15.9124        0.500000        0.500000    
    201001010200      00002     91.2323         93.8417         95.9578         99.0000         99.0000         99.0000         99.0000         99.0000         99.0000         98.9829         88.4616         82.8682         59.4900         59.4900         16.8052         16.8052        0.500000        0.500000    
    201001010300      00002     94.3013         97.2262         99.0000         99.0000         99.0000         99.0000         98.6965         99.0000         99.0000         99.0000         87.7681         85.6374         51.5871         51.5871         19.4833         19.4833        0.500000        0.500000    
    201001010400      00002     95.2143         98.3831         99.0000         99.0000         98.9409         97.9819         99.0000         99.0000         98.6090         89.6825         85.1337         84.1001         47.7453         47.7453         20.1295         20.1295        0.500000        0.500000    
    201001010500      00002     94.9904         98.2644         99.0000         97.4757         94.7400         96.5887         99.0000         99.0000         98.1337         89.6765         88.0377         80.0048         47.3583         47.3583         23.5985         23.5985        0.500000        0.500000
```

Comment: Do all the variables end up in a single column or is the first variable the only one that's loaded?

Comment: @thepule All the variables end up in a single column. In other words the width is compensated with length.

Comment: Are you sure your file is tab separated and the file is uniform after 10 lines?

Comment: @Psidom Yes, that way I am wondering this is happening. I also tried to import it in r studio with tools menu, but it ended up the same having one column.

Comment: It seems something specific to the file you are reading. If you use Rstudio, have you tried to import the file using the *import dataset* functionality? It usually does a good job at identifying the right procedure to load the file. Also the correspondent code is shown in the console, so you can grab it and use it in your code in the future.

Comment: @G1124E can you post a small sample of your text file?

Comment: @thepule Yes, I used the import functionality and got the same result.

Comment: @thecatalyst Above is some of the data. You can skip 4 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have different nr. of columns in your file (21 in line 5 VS 20 in the lines beyond line 5).

Similar to what @thepule suggested, with `read.table` you can just leave out the `sep` parameter completely, and `read.table` usually give you good results by doing something reasonable automatically. In your case, with leaving out line 1-5, this results in 8 lines with 20 variables:

```
> f <- read.table('file.txt', header=FALSE, skip=5) 
> str(f)

 data.frame':   8 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ V1 : num  2.01e+11 2.01e+11 2.01e+11 2.01e+11 2.01e+11 ...
 $ V2 : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 $ V3 : num  86.9 91.2 94.3 95.2 95 ...
 [...]
```

Setting `sep=''`, which skips all white spaces in between columns would work as well in your case.

**Edit:** in case you have different amount of columns (=elements) per row you could consider setting `fill=T` in `read.table`. This will fill up missing information with blank fields - but make sure that this is what you actually *want* to do.

PS: `file` would be a function, so I'd recommend using another name for your variable.

Comment: I used your solution but I got error message that say: `Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 8762 did not have 20 elements`

Comment: This indicates that your data file does not provide the same amount of columns per row (line 6-8761 all have 20 elements, but line 8762 has a different amount). You could consider setting `fill=T`, but make sure that this is really what you *want* to do.

Comment: May I say something? Your `fill=TRUE` worked. Thank you. You are awesome!